# How can I add progressbar before the load data from firebase and dismiss this progressbar after loaded data from firebase with firebasercycler adapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I was created one application, in this application I used firebase and firebaserecycler adapter. I can load data, it works fine. But I want add progressbar until data is loaded and dismiss it after the data is loaded. Is anyone have some experience with this?

My Fragment is this //

```
    public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;

    RecyclerView listCategory;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CategoryViewHolder> adapter;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference categories;

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance(){
    CategoryFragment categoryfragment = new CategoryFragment();
    return categoryfragment;
    }

    public CategoryFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    categories = database.getReference("Category");

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
    container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, 
    false);

    listCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
    listCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext());
    listCategory.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadCategories();

    return view;
    }

    private void loadCategories(){
    adapter =  new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CategoryViewHolder>
       (
            Category.class,
            R.layout.category_layout,
            CategoryViewHolder.class,
            categories
       ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, 
        final Category model, int position) {
            viewHolder.category_name.setText(model.getName());

            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean 
         isLongClick) {
                    Intent game = new Intent(getActivity(),Start.class);
                    Common.categoryId = 
         adapter.getRef(position).getKey();
                    startActivity(game);
                }
            });
        }
       };
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       listCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
       }
```

My xml file is this //

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".CategoryFragment">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listCategory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

  </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, this can be solved very simple. Create a new object of `ProgressBar` and start showing it in the `onCreate()` method, or if you want, add it directly in your .XML file. Finally in your adapter class, override the following method:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged() {
    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

P.S. You are using a very old version of the [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library. Please update to the latest version.

Comment: This is the complete code. You should implement this method inside your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` class. It should be places near the other methods like `populateViewHolder()`, right?